# What do I need to do to set up usb audio gadget i/o on a beaglebone running debian?

Tags: audio, usb, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

I want to use alsa on a Beaglebone Black to send audio through usb audio out and receive it on my computer.

I have seen that there are some gadgets in a legacy folder in the kernel, and seen some tutorials on how to set up mass storage and network gadgets, but I am confused about what the state of audio gadgets is and what to compile and configure for this.

Can you explain the various components and configurations that need to go into place to make this happen, covering which kernel modules, drivers, kinds of scripts, and configurations that might be needed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable USB gadget subsystem in your Linux kernel for Beaglebone Black. Assuming of course that you have USB device controller and USB device connector on your Beaglebone. Here there are more information:

https://www.lynxbee.com/usb-audio-gadget-driver/

USB devices contains so called USB descriptors which tells USB host (PC) as a what device type it works. Audio gadget is one of the type of that descriptor that tells that this device (in this case BeagleBone) should be working as a audio device.